# Make Select Menu Revert on Cancel Dialogue

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a system in which a user can change a select drop down and it will give them a prompt to ensure they want to take the action. Here is my code:

```
function changeResStatus(str1) {
    var id = str1;
    var status = document.getElementById("resstatus" + id).value;

    var r = confirm("Change status for ID # " + id + " to " + status + "?");
    if (r == true) {
        console.log ("change made");

    }else{
        console.log ("change not made");
    }
}
```

In the event the change is not made, I would like the select menu to go back to the previous option it was before the user attempted to change it. How would I do that?

Comment: so if user click on cancel, last selected option should be reset ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If the user clicks cancel it should revert (or reset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one.

```js
$(document).on('change','.mydropdown',function(){

var previousValue = $(this).attr("data-previousvalue");
var r = confirm("Change status for");
if (r == true) 
{
   $(this).attr("data-previousvalue",$(this).val())
}
else
{
   $(this).val($(this).attr("data-previousvalue"));
}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  class="mydropdown" data-previousvalue="0">
<option value="0">select something</option>
<option value="1">something 1</option>
<option value="2">something 2</option>
<option value="3">something 3</option>
</select>

<select  class="mydropdown" data-previousvalue="0">
<option value="0">select something</option>
<option value="101">something 101</option>
<option value="102">something 102</option>
<option value="103">something 103</option>
</select>

<select class="mydropdown" data-previousvalue="0">
<option value="0">select something</option>
<option value="201">something 201</option>
<option value="202">something 202</option>
<option value="202">something 203</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, one more thing - the select boxes are generated dynamically, so this would have to work with the "onclick" or "onfocus" option, could you adjust your answer to fit that?

Comment: you can check now, you need to apply common class on your dropdown and need to manage varibales for each dropdown

Comment: I'm sorry, you didn't understand, I have multiple dynamically generated select boxes I need to do this with. I need them to work for all of them... could you modify the code to work with that?

Comment: ok, updated. now you can use it for any no of dynamic dropdown.